# Simple String error, String breaking from ' in var

Tags: string

the parsing of user name has a ' inside of the user name
and i think that is causing the code to break
when i set it with this

tempUsername=Request.Form("UserName")

```
if (Request.Form("Action") = "Login") then
    tempUsername=Request.Form("UserName")
    tempPassword=Request.Form("UserPassword")
```

is that assumption right?
if so what is a solution to this?

Comment: `tempUsername=Request.Form` -- what language  is being used there? And why is this tagged PHP?

Comment: this is a php app, so i think everything should be in php. i will edit the question with a code block.

Comment: @VictorWeng - I'm pretty sure that's not PHP

Comment: hmm.. it is using these and not <?php to start off the code <%, i will search and see what lang that is.

Comment: that is definitely NOT php. It's probably VBscript or something similar, that happens to be getting spit out by a PHP app.

Comment: the error points me to a link of iss7 with no error message

Comment: seems like its asp codes i think ?

Comment: This is why tutorials and a decent amount of learning any language first is am absolute must. You've copied code and are stuck with it, probably at a basic level, and are trying to ask help on code you don't understand and don't even know what language it is. Honestly, I know it sounds blunt and that is not intended, but spend time (days, weeks, months) learning the basics etc first, then code, then test, then try again, then search for answers, THEN ask questions. :)

Comment: @VictorWeng you had a PHP tag but said "seems like its asp codes i think ?", and "did not look into the language to double check", both gives an impression you're unsure on some fundamental details required for asking a decent question. Understanding your own code and providing clear info before asking is needed to get a good answer, and only fair. I can't answer you if you don't know the question. However no harm done as discussions found the root issue, and I wasn't being bitter, just precise and gave advice based on the info and impression of your knowledge which you provided. Good luck :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jumping onto the comment by James, as well as answering this question:

Input sanitization is an issue in *every* language. Even if there weren't `'` characters in usernames, this code is danger++

At the very least, run all the data you get from `Request.form` through a function that escapes/sanitizes dangerous characters in the context of what the data is getting passed on to (such as data stores or dir-resolving code).

As for the code using `<%`, that's a sign this is an ASP script, and the syntax looks like it's VB. The `(Request.Form("Action") = "Login")` in particular is a dead give-away, because no sane programming language since the 80s uses "=" as an equality testing operator =)

Comment: Thanks for the input found out the issue to be the ' is breaking the sql query which is what is causing the error.

Comment: never pass user input straight into SQL as a query. Use prepared statements or statement filtering so that you can say `execute("INSERT INTO users (username) VALUES (?)", Request.form("username"))`, and have the libary that owns the execute function do sanitizing. Never, ever, use a straight query if user input is involved. It's not potentially problematic, it's knowingly introducing, or leaving, an exploitable security vulnerability in your code. One that can even be found with some simple trial and error, and THEN exploited. Lesson: fix the code beyond what this question was for.